# Applet error in html5

Tags: java, applet

When I run my html file, it gives me this error:

> noclassdefFoundError, applet(wrong name:testapplet/applet)
>   details
>
> Java Plug-in 10.65.2.20
>
> Using JRE version 1.7.0_65-b20 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

applet.class and applet.html are in the same folder: `\testapplet\bin\testapplet`.

Applet code:

```
package testapplet;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class applet extends JApplet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Acesta este un applet",320,180);
    }
}
```

Html code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applet app</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <embed type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.7"
           width="512" height="512"
           code="applet.class" 
     />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your applet class is in `testapplet` package, put the html file in the parent directory i.e. inside bin in this case.

You should not put `applet.html` i the same folder as `applet.class` if you applet class has a package specified.

This should work.

Comment: Really? was that simple? It works, and now i understand where was the problem. Thank you very much man.

Comment: I am glad that it helped. feel free to mark the answer if it helps you